# Can't unlock the .300 Knockout?

Tags: battlefield-hardline

So I've completed the requirements to unlock the .300 knockout weeks ago now. All I need now is to complete the 4 challenges then I unlock it. However, for some reason they don't show up! [image]
Anyone know how to fix this?